# Don't update component until image loaded

Tags: vue.js

I have an CurrentItem component, which shows an image and a description of some item. The item regularly changes based on events from the server. The problem I'm having is that when it does, the new item's image takes a few moments to load during which time the component just has a big blank space where the image is supposed to go, which does not look good.

What I would prefer instead is to keep showing the old item until the new item's image is loaded, and only at that point update the component. Is there a simple way to achieve that?

**Some example code:**

For the purposes of the question, you can think of an item as a simple JSON structure:

```
{
  "id": "ABC123",
  "description": "A fine yellow specimen",
  "image": "//example.com/images/ABC123.jpeg"
}
```

The events from the server JSON over a WebSocket, and look something like this:

```
{ "nextItemId": "ABC124" }
```

When we receive one of those, we send a GET request to fetch the next item at `//example.com/items/ABC124.json`.

Comment: Can you show code indicating where/how you receive the event from the server and what info it contains?  Some simple example makes it easier to demonstrate  (does it receive raw image data?  a url?  an index to an existing data set?)

Answer (score 2):

Preload the image and wait for its `onload` event to fire before setting the `item`:

```js
methods: {
   onReceived(newItem) {
      const image = new Image();  // Create new empty image
      image.onload = () => {      // CALLBACK:  Will fire when image is done loading
         this.item = newItem;         // Will set the current item
         this.isLoading = false;      // Will stop animation
      }
      this.isLoading = true;      // Start animation
      image.src = newItem.image;  // Begin loading 
   }
}
```

Once it's finished, the current item will be set.  Here's a demo with a large image:

```js
Vue.component('item', {
  props: ['item'],
  template: `
  <div>
    <div>ITEM (id: {{ item.id }})</div>
    <div>{{ item.description }}</div>
    <div><img :src="item.image" ref="img" width="100" height="100" /></div>
  </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
      item: {
        "id": "ABC123",
        "description": "A fine yellow specimen",
        "image": "https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/google-470-675827.png"
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    simulateEvent() {
      this.onReceived({
        "id": "ZYX987",
        "description":  "A funky jaundiced specimen",
        "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Very_Large_Array_in_New_Mexico.jpg"
      });
    },
    onReceived(newItem) {
      this.isLoading = true;
      const image = new Image();
      image.onload = () => {
        this.item = newItem;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
      image.src = newItem.image;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <item :item="item"></item>
  
  <!-- Simulating events -->
  <button @click="simulateEvent">
  Simulate event
  </button>
  <span v-if="isLoading">[ Loading... ]</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my own best shot at a solution.

Basically my idea is to have another copy of `<CurrentItem />` in the DOM which has `display:none;` and which holds the item that is about to be the current. Then, when the image in that component is loaded, we update our actual CurrentItem. Something like this:

```
<template>
  <CurrentItem
    :key="currentItemId"
    :item="currentItem"
  />
  <CurrentItem
    :key="aboutToBecomeCurrentItemId"
    :item="aboutToBecomeCurrentItem"
    @imageLoaded="onImageReady"
    style="display:none;"
  />
</template>

<script>
// ...

export default {
  // ...

  data() {
    return {
      currentItem = null,
      aboutToBecomeCurrentItem = null
    },

    methods: {
      onItemUpdated(newItem) {
        this.aboutToBecomeCurrentItem = newItem;
      },
  
      onImageReady() {
        this.currentItem = this.aboutToBecomeCurrentItem;
      }
    }
  }

  // ...
}
</script>
```

I think this would work, but I would love to know it if there are simpler or more idiomatic ways to achieve the same.

Answer (score -1):

you can set a time out function until the image loads

```
 .. codes to load new image
 setTimeout(function() {
      ... your old image codes
      ... 5000 means 5Seconds
  },5000);
.. codes to display new image
```

Comment: That's not a solution to the problem I described. I specifically said that I wanted to keep showing the old item until the new item was ready.